# Combine/Extend 2 raids

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid5

I have two Raids, raid5(md0) and a raid1(md128).
How can I extend "/"? OS is now on raid 5.

```
    root@backup:~# cat /proc/mdstat
    Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
    md128 : active raid1 sde1[1] sdd1[0]
          2930134016 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
          bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

    md0 : active raid5 sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
          1953259520 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
          bitmap: 3/8 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk


    root@backup:~# df -T
    Filesystem     Type      1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
    udev           devtmpfs    1841008       0    1841008   0% /dev
    tmpfs          tmpfs        378804   10440     368364   3% /run
    /dev/md0p1     ext4     1918608432 1800052 1819325628   1% /
    tmpfs          tmpfs       1894020       0    1894020   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs          tmpfs          5120       0       5120   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs          tmpfs       1894020       0    1894020   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs          tmpfs        378804       0     378804   0% /run/user/0


root@backup:~# sudo lsblk -f
    NAME        FSTYPE            LABEL            UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
    sda
    └─sda1      linux_raid_member backup:0         9c8af56c-1472-3844-c14b-5ff1fd2469cc
      └─md0
        ├─md0p1 ext4                               9f23d9b1-5573-4adb-bd98-11c06dc46602   /
        ├─md0p2
        └─md0p5 swap                               5e5c48d6-2fde-48b8-845b-796c9980e9c5   [SWAP]
    sdb
    └─sdb1      linux_raid_member backup:0         9c8af56c-1472-3844-c14b-5ff1fd2469cc
      └─md0
        ├─md0p1 ext4                               9f23d9b1-5573-4adb-bd98-11c06dc46602   /
        ├─md0p2
        └─md0p5 swap                               5e5c48d6-2fde-48b8-845b-796c9980e9c5   [SWAP]
    sdc
    └─sdc1      linux_raid_member backup:0         9c8af56c-1472-3844-c14b-5ff1fd2469cc
      └─md0
        ├─md0p1 ext4                               9f23d9b1-5573-4adb-bd98-11c06dc46602   /
        ├─md0p2
        └─md0p5 swap                               5e5c48d6-2fde-48b8-845b-796c9980e9c5   [SWAP]
    sdd
    └─sdd1      linux_raid_member 192-168-0-11:128 d4539e00-7885-2a62-84a0-94c1884e253c
      └─md128   LVM2_member                        wp1Qak-hzu5-Eb2q-JNvb-aceu-mhQf-703K5N
    sde
    └─sde1      linux_raid_member 192-168-0-11:128 d4539e00-7885-2a62-84a0-94c1884e253c
      └─md128   LVM2_member                        wp1Qak-hzu5-Eb2q-JNvb-aceu-mhQf-703K5N


root@backup:~# dumpe2fs /dev/md128 | grep -i superblock
    dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
    dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md128
    Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Comment: Not really sure what you want. From your root partition, there is only 1% used - so why extend that?

Comment: Yeah but my root partition use only the first raid. I want to mount, extend /, combine the space of two raids over / partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your root partition is not based on LVM, so the way to expand the filesystem has to be expanding the RAID `md0`. The output of `lsblk` suggests there is an LVM installation on your `md128`, but I don't know if there are logical volumes (and therefore maybe active data) on that drive. You could find out with `pvscan`, `vgscan`and `lvscan`.

**Before continuing, make sure you have a valid backup of all your valuable data!!**

If there are no (valuable) data/no mounted partitions on md128, you can just stop `md128` and add the two disks to your `md0` to first increase the total space on `/dev/md0`:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md128                   # this will break the md128
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdd2  # this will add two hot spares to md0
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=5    # this will extend md0 to five disks
```

This could take a very long time (hours to days), as the RAID has to be resynced.

**If there is an mdadm config file (`/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`) , you will have to change that to reflect the new configuration.**

Now that `/dev/md0` has been increased (you may see with `fdisk -l /dev/md0`), you have to increase the root partition. As `/`is on md0p1 and `swap` on `md0p5`, which is a logical partition in the extended partition `md0p2`, you first need to move `md0p5`/`md0p2`to the end of `md0`. You can do this with `gparted`. As the `gparted`[feature list](http://gparted.org/features.php) says that RAID is only supported in *offline* mode, you will have to reboot from an installation medium to `try ubuntu`mode and then start `gparted`.

Select `md0`as the device to change, then move the extended partition (`md0p2`) to the end of the 'disk', and afterwards increase `/dev/md0p1`. This should resize the filesystem too; so in the end your root partition and filesystem will be increased.

**Be aware that this process is not without risk, especially if you are new to linux/raid/filesystems**. I am not able to describe the process in all details with pictures, as I do not use mdraid at the moment.

As there is already a RAID1 on sdd/sde with maybe LVM prepared, you might also do an easier (and less risky) solution, moving some data to a filesystem on the second RAID and mount that somewhere below `/` (e.g. move `home`). If that would be practicable to you, I could give support for that, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I removed the first raid, was raid5 3x1TB and now I have only one raid 3x3TB. And reinstalled the OS again with LVM this time for root partition :)